# How to skip php unittests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am running phpunit 3.2.8 on a system (without the possibility to update the version of this code), and want to skip certain php unittests. How can I do this?

In python, you simply can add a decorator before the test-function to make it skip. How can I do it for php with the specified version of phpunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mark it skipped like so:

```
class SomeTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $this->markTestSkipped();
        // rest of test here ...
    }
}
```